# I use as.complex() to convert a string column to a numeric column in r

Tags: r

I have three columns which are characters A, B, and C respectively. I am using is.numeric to convert them to numeric and then assign them values e.g. 1,2 and 3, but when I am using is.numeric(). it returns back NAs. In different data frames these orders vary, e.g. ABC or ACB, but A=i+0i, B=2+3i and C is also a complex number. I want to first convert the string to a complex number and then assign values to them.

```
LV$phase1 <- as.numeric(LV$phase1)
class(phase1)
A=1
print(phase1)
```

This is the error:
"Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion "

Comment: because some characters cannot be converted to numeric. eg `as.numeric('A')` will be `NA`

Answer (score 0):

It does not usually make sense to convert character data to numeric, but if the letters refer to an ordered sequence of events/phases/periods, then it may be useful. R uses factors for this purpose. For example

```
set.seed(42)
phase <- sample(LETTERS[1:4], 10, replace=TRUE)
phase
# [1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "D" "B" "B" "A" "D"
factor(phase)
#  [1] A A A A B D B B A D
Levels: A B D
as.numeric(factor(phase))
#  [1] 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 3
```

If this is what you are trying to do

```
LV$phase1 <- as.numeric(factor(LV$phase1))
```

will convert the letters to an ordered sequence and assign numbers to represent those categories.

Comment: Thank you, it is just working for one column, and nothing happens for the two other columns.
```
LV$phase1 <- as.numeric(factor(LV$phase1))
LV$phase2 <- as.numeric(factor(LV$phase2))
LV$phase3 <- as.numeric(factor(LV$phase3))
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Is there an error message or is the column still characters? What does `str(LV)` return? Does it show any differences in data type, between the three columns?

Comment: Sorry, it is working, but It makes all three columns 1+0i.

Comment: Strange. That would be a complex number. Without reproducible data or even `str(LV)` there is no way to figure out what is going on.